# Sorting Nested List with Object List

Tags: python, list, sorting, nested

Hello I am trying to figure out how to sort a nested list by multiple variables while some will not be sorted by 1,2,3 and instead by a predetermined list.

For Example:

```
List=[[XD,1],[XD,3],[XD,2],[X5,2],[X5,3],[XT,2]]
```

This would result in:

```
[[XD,1],[XD,2],[XD,3],[XT,2],[X5,2],[X5,3]]
```

The first element would be sorted by the sortbylist and the second element simply in numerical order.

```
SortByList={'XD': 'A', 'XT':'B', 'XQ': 'C','X5': 'D'}
```

I have currently been trying to use the code:

```
List.sort(key=SortByList.__getitem__  x: x[0])
List=sorted(List,key=itemgetter(1))
```

This however does not seem to work. Any hints?

One of the easiest ways to do this is:

```
Result=sorted(List, key=lambda x:(SortByList[x[0]],x[1]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
In [2]: List=[['XD',1],['XD',3],['XD',2],['X5',2],['X5',3],['XT',2]]

In [3]: SortByList={'XD': 'A', 'XT':'B', 'XQ': 'C','X5': 'D'}

In [4]: sorted(List, key=lambda x:(SortByList[x[0]],x[1]))
Out[4]: [['XD', 1], ['XD', 2], ['XD', 3], ['XT', 2], ['X5', 2], ['X5', 3]]
```

This uses a two-element compound key as explained in your question.

Comment: This works perfectly fine when running it directly in python. However when you place this inside of a program it does not seem to sort the list. Any ideas?

Comment: @Ophion: This code simply prints out the result; it doesn't assign it back to `List`. Either change it to `List = sorted(List, key=...)` or use `List.sort(key=...)`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are trying to sort objects using their name to get the sort order, but your objects don't have any reference to what their name is.  There is no way to tell from your object `XD` that it is called `'XD'` except by searching for it in `locals()` or `globals()`.

Your best option here is to store your variables in a dictionary rather than in directly in the scope/namespace.  So change your code from this:

```
XD = MyObject(...)
X5 = MyObject(...)
XT = MyObject(...)
List=[[XD,1],[XD,3],[XD,2],[X5,2],[X5,3],[XT,2]]
```

To this:

```
XDict = {'XD': MyObject(...),
         'X5': MyObject(...),
         'XT': MyObject(...)}
List = [[XDict['XD'],1],[XDict['XD'],3],[XDict['XD'],2],
        [XDict['X5'],2],[XDict['X5'],3],[XDict['XT'],2]]
```

The contents of `List` will be exactly the same, but now you have a way to associate the names `'XD'`, `'X5'`, and `'XT'` with an object, so when defining `SortList` you can create a list of the actual objects by their name:

```
SortByList=[XDict.get('XD'), XDict.get('XT'), XDict.get('XQ'), XDict.get('X5')]
sorted(List, key=lambda k, i: (SortedByList.index(k), i))
```

By doing it this way you can create your `SortByList` even when some variables are undefined, like `XQ` would be in this example.  That entry in `SortByList` would just be `None`, which wouldn't cause any problems when the other elements are sorted.

Comment: I was hoping that there was a simpler answer to this. If the suggestion by aix doesn't work I will use this. Thank you for the input.